# Error when Sending Messages to Skype for Business Bot Framework Bot

Tags: botframework, skype, office365api, office365-apps, skype-for-business

I'm having an issue with a Skype for Business bot in one of my Office 365 tenants. I have multiple tenants and in the first one I was able to add a Skype for Business bot framework bot with no issues. It took awhile for the bot to show up in the directory but it worked. In my second tenant, when I add the bot and attempt to send messages to it (even after 12ish hours of waiting), Skype for Business shows an error under each message I try to send to it - "The action couldn’t be completed. Please try again later." Any ideas what might be going on? One difference between the tenants is that the tenant that isn't working ha a custom domain name, and is using Azure AD Synchronization. Based on some tips I saw I made the address of my bot sip:username@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com rather than using my custom domain name. That didn't seem to make a difference... anyone else encountered this/have any ideas? I also tried leaving off the [BotAuthentication] tag on my MessagesController and that did not make a difference as well.

EDIT: Could this have something to do with my custom domain being federated? That's why I went with mytenant.onmicrosoft.com for the username of the bot.

Comment: I am having a similar issue but instead of saying that it says "We couldn't send this message..." like when you chat with a user that is not online on SFB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. It seems like it has something to do with when you add a bot to a federated domain utilizing the custom domain name. This errors out when you use the New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -Uri bot@domain.com. However, it still creates a bad endpoint. The cmdlet does not error out if you use a uri like bot@domain.onmicrosoft.com. However, after I had already added the bad endpoint, it seemed like no endpoints would work after that. To resolve, I removed all endpoints, including the first bad one with the uri bot@domain.com. Waited 8 hours, added a single endpoint using the onmicrosoft.com Office 365 domain, waited probably about 12 hours, and it started working.